# Count my customer in one Query In Spring boot

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

**I have a table in which I store customer information such as customer name and type
like this**

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 | Gold |
| 2 | c2 | Silver |
| 3 | c3 | Bronze |
| 4 | c4 | Usual |
| 5 | c5 | Gold |
| 6 | c6 | Gold |
| 7 | c7 | Silver |

And need to find the number of each type of customer

For example, number of gold customers?
Gold = 3 , Silver = 2 , Bronze = 1 , Usual = 1

Can anyone solve my problem?

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(p.gold) AS gold , COUNT(p.silver) AS silver , COUNT(p.bronze) AS bronze , COUNT(p.usual) AS usual  from Customer p")
MyModel selectTotals();
```

Comment: You're looking for `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how your sql query should look like:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(case when p.type= 'gold' then 1 end) AS gold 
  , COUNT(case when p.type= 'silver' then 1 end) AS silver 
  , COUNT(case when p.type= 'bronze' then 1 end) AS bronze 
  , COUNT(case when p.type= 'usual' then 1 end) AS usual  
from Customer p
```

Comment: This will return more than one row

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it's a global aggregation , it only returns one row.

Comment: Ah now I see it. There are only aggregate functions in the select. Stupid me

Answer (score 0):

You can try with STUFF and Group By, If you want the results in one row

```
SELECT result = (STUFF((
select ', ' + type + '=' + cast(count(*) as varchar)
from Customer 
group by type
having count(*)>5
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    )
```